# mongodb Join on Entire Collection Using $lookup

Tags: mongodb, left-join, lookup

I'm struggling how to do a join in mongodb using `$lookup`. I want this join to happen whenever the `game` collection is called upon.

I have two collections: `game` and `boxart`.

`game` collection

```
{ "guid": 123, name: "Halo" }
```

`boxart` collection

```
{ "releaseId": 123, image: "https://someurl.com/image.jpg" }
```

**index.js**

```
MongoClient.connect(dbConfig.url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, database) => {

  db = database.db("cello_db");
  db.collection('game')
    .aggregate([
      { $lookup:
        {
          from: 'boxart',
          localField: 'releaseId',
          foreignField: 'guid',
          as: 'art'
        }
      },
    ]);

  require('./routes')(app, db);

});
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.get('/games', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('game').find().toArray((err, games) => {
      res.send(games);
    });
  });
};
```

When I call my `/games` endpoint however, I don't get the joined collection. What I expect to get is this:

```
{ "guid": 123, name: "Halo", art: { "releaseId": 123, image: "https://someurl.com/image.jpg" } }
```

What I ACTUALLY get is this:

```
{ "guid": 123, name: "Halo" }
```

I'm clearly not doing something right. I'm new to the backend and have only used mongodb for a couple of hours. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is how $lookup behave  ... If you are looking left join like operator attributes from both then you should look for for each...  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I think you have localField and foreignField reversed

Comment: Switch your local and ForeignField. `{ $lookup:
        {
          from: 'boxart',
          localField: 'guid',
          foreignField: 'releaseId',
          as: 'art'
        }
      },`